# Можно ли выводить модель в представлении с HttpGet и одновременно дополнять модель с той же инфой с помощью HttpPost формы?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Я новичок в C# и в ASP.NET MVC. Я передаю в одной модели LessonPassViewModel

```
    public class LessonPassViewModel
    {
        public int LessonId { get; set; }

        public List<TestQuestionViewModel> TestQuestions { get; set; }
 
        public List<OpenQuestionViewModel> OpenQuestions { get; set; }

        public List<bool>? TasksCorrectness { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "Ответ должен быть меньше 500 символов!")]

        public List<string> UserAnswers { get; set; }
    }
```

информацию через метод контроллера HttpGet (когда я передаю модель в представление, она передаётся с заполненными свойствами TestQuestion, OpenQuestion и LessonId и пустыми UserAnswers,TasksCorrectness). После этого я хочу дозаполнить эту же модель у которой заполнены те три свойства, а именно дозаполнить свойство модели "UserAnswers" с помощью формы. и передать эти 4 заполненных свойства в Метод контроллера HttpPost, где ожидается заполнение последнего свойства модели, а именно "TasksCorrectness" и возврат вот этой всей полностью заполненной модели на то же представление с полностью заполненными всеми свойствами. Код контроллеров ниже:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PassLesson(int id)
        {
            var response = await _basicTeachingService.GetQuestions(id); //Здесь заполняются 3 свойства у модели LessonPassViewModel

            if (response.StatusCode == Domain.Enum.StatusCode.OK)
            {
                return View(response.Data);
            }
            return View("Error", $"{response.Description}");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PassLesson(LessonPassViewModel model) //Предполагаемый возврат через post с той же моделью, заполненной уже 4-мя свойствами
        {
            var response = await _basicTeachingService.PassLesson(model, User.Identity.Name); //Дозаполнение последнего свойства
            if (response.StatusCode == Domain.Enum.StatusCode.OK)
            {
                return View(response.Data);
            }
            return View("Error", $"{response.Description}");
        }
```

При отправке с формы в метод контроллера передаётся модель лишь с одним свойством UserAnswers, а не вся

Я понимаю, что можно просто заново заполнить в HttpPost первые три свойства, по сути заново создав объект модели, но уже с 4мя заполненными свойствами. Но мне интересно, можно ли прогнать эту же модель? Или надо создавать новый экземпляр? Что можете мне посоветовать?

Comment: Вы сейчас хотите сохранить контекст работы с пользователем. В asp.net web forms такой функционал предоставляется из "коробки" (не надо туда лезть), mvc создавался как раз для того что бы сделать работу клиента с сервером более прозрачной, легковесной и переносимой. Если что то можно получить на сервере, то лучше получать это на сервере не передавая на клиент. Вот когда у вас будут высокие нагрузки от большого количества пользователей, тогда нужно задумываться над тем как бы часть инфы отправить клиенту.